# awk sub check element and add entry to a list

Tags: string, awk, substring, substitution

I've a string:

```sh
1   9790725 .   TTCCTCC T   .   .   ACMG=US;benign_cv=0;ccds_transcript=true;clingen=0
1   9790725 .   TTCCTCC T   .   .   ACMG=US;benign_cv=0;accepted=entry0,entry1;ccds_transcript=true;clingen=1
```

I need to check if the element `accepted=entry0,entry1,...,entryN;` is already in last column. In case:

- is already **present** (as in line 2 of example): add an element (e.g. `entryX`) among its comma separated values list. (e.g. to get `accepted=entry0,entry1,entryX;` from `accepted=entry0,entry1;` in line 2 of example)
- is **absent** (as in line 1 of the example) add it as `accepted=entryX;`.

NB: can also be a single element one (e.g. `accepted=entry0;` without commas in it)

I tried this command:

```sh
awk  -F'\t' '$2 == "9790725" { if ($0 ~ /\;accepted=/) { sub(/accepted=[^;]*/,"accepted=entryX" ) } else { sub(/(accepted=.*)?$/,";accepted=entryX;") } } 1' file
```

but I was only able to replace its values or create it if absent, not appending to the list of entries...

How can I do it with `awk` command `sub`?

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String functions documentation : https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

With sub:

> If the special character ‘&’ appears in replacement, it stands for the precise substring that was matched by regexp.

```
awk  '
$2 == 9790725{
    if ($0 ~ /\;accepted=/){
        sub(/accepted=[^;]*/,"&,entryX")
    } 
    else{
        sub(/$/,";accepted=entryX;")
    }
}1' file
```

Result :

```
1   9790725 .   TTCCTCC T   .   .   ACMG=US;benign_cv=0;ccds_transcript=true;clingen=0;accepted=entryX;
1   9790725 .   TTCCTCC T   .   .   ACMG=US;benign_cv=0;accepted=entry0,entry1,entryX;ccds_transcript=true;clingen=1
```

Be aware that you could also use groups with GNU awk and gensub function. No need here but it can be useful for more complex substitutions.

> gensub() provides an additional feature that is not available in sub()
>   or gsub(): the ability to specify components of a regexp in the
>   replacement text. This is done by using parentheses in the regexp to
>   mark the components and then specifying ‘\N’ in the replacement text,
>   where N is a digit from 1 to 9.

---

To answer to your comment :

Let's suppose you have this input :

```
1   9790725 .   TTCCTCC T   .   .   ACMG=US;benign_cv=0;ccds_transcript=true;clingen=0
1   9790725 .   TTCCTCC T   .   .   ACMG=US;benign_cv=0;accepted=entry0,entry1;ccds_transcript=true;clingen=1
1   9790725 .   TTCCTCC T   .   .   ACMG=US;benign_cv=0;accepted=entry0,entry1;ccds_transcript=true;clingen=1;rejected=entry2
1   9790725 .   TTCCTCC T   .   .   ACMG=US;benign_cv=0;accepted=entry0,entry1,entry2;ccds_transcript=true;clingen=1
```

And you want to add entry2 :
- first line does not have accepted field
- third one rejects entry2
- fourth one already has entry2.

I adapted my script to handle these rows :

```
awk -v entry="entry2" '
($2 == 9790725) && \
!($0 ~ "accepted=[^;]*" entry) && \ 
!($0 ~ "rejected=[^;]*" entry){
    if ($0 ~ /\;accepted=/){
        sub(/accepted=[^;]*/,"&," entry)
    } 
    else{
        sub(/$/,";accepted=" entry ";")
    }
}1' file
```

Now, awk will check if entry is already in accepted or rejected before appending it. Remove one of these conditions if you want a different behavior.

```
1   9790725 .   TTCCTCC T   .   .   ACMG=US;benign_cv=0;ccds_transcript=true;clingen=0;accepted=entry2;
1   9790725 .   TTCCTCC T   .   .   ACMG=US;benign_cv=0;accepted=entry0,entry1,entry2;ccds_transcript=true;clingen=1
1   9790725 .   TTCCTCC T   .   .   ACMG=US;benign_cv=0;accepted=entry0,entry1;ccds_transcript=true;clingen=1;rejected=entry2
1   9790725 .   TTCCTCC T   .   .   ACMG=US;benign_cv=0;accepted=entry0,entry1,entry2;ccds_transcript=true;clingen=1
```

I think that the structure of the file is not adapted (it looks like a csv with multiple field separators and columns that are sometimes absent or in different orders). It would be easier with a `json` type of structure and an adapted tool to read/update it (not `awk`).

You could also use `split` function to handle this file in awk (and split on `=`, `;`, `,`). I'm too lazy to try it and would prefer a better file structure.

Comment: Thank you @corentin ! That's great! And what about if, in order to avoid duplicates, I need to check if the particular `userX` is already in the list before adding it? I also have a field `rejcted=user0,user1,...,userN` so I can not just operate a search for the `userX` in string, cause it could be in `rejected` field. Sorry if I'm asking a sub-question but it's something I realized right now. I'll accept your answer anyway.

Comment: @cccnrc not sure to understand. If user is already in `accepted` or `rejected`, you shouldn't add it in both cases right ? I edited with a solution that could fit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    if ( match($0,/accepted=[^;]+/) ) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART+RLENGTH-1) ",entryX" substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    else {
        $0 = $0 ";accepted=entryX"
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1       9790725 .       TTCCTCC T       .       .       ACMG=US;benign_cv=0;ccds_transcript=true;clingen=0;accepted=entryX
1       9790725 .       TTCCTCC T       .       .       ACMG=US;benign_cv=0;accepted=entry0,entry1,entryX;ccds_transcript=true;clingen=1
```